# Tailwind styles not working on production

Tags: create-react-app, tailwind-css, netlify, vercel

I've built a creat-react-app application and deployed it into Netlify (https://festive-booth-3f3a79.netlify.app/) but as you can see, for some reason styles are not being loaded.

I've tried to deploy the app with Vercel, but I've the same problem.

This is my *`tailwind.config.js`*

```
module.exports = {
  important: true,
  // Active dark mode on class basis
  darkMode: "class",
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
  },
  purge: {
    content: ["./pages/**/*.tsx", "./components/**/*.tsx"],
    // These options are passed through directly to PurgeCSS
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ["checked"],
      borderColor: ["checked"],
      inset: ["checked"],
      zIndex: ["hover", "active"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  future: {
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
};
```

Here you can check all the others files I have: https://gitlab.com/lucas.distasi/react-tmdb

Running on my local with `yarn start` inside the build folder created after `yarn run build` works perfectly fine. So I'm guessing it's a problem with the Tailwind CSS files when deploying on a remote server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74893538/20953630
Thanks, it has work, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, the problem was that I was pointing to the wrong folders in the purge object. So, modifying what I had with this:

```
purge: {
    content: ["./src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"]
    // These options are passed through directly to PurgeCSS
  }
```

Makes the page to display properly.
The directory might be different in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the "tw-elements.js"?

If dont, use the useEffect() to to "import tw-elements" (in file _app.js):

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout"

import "../styles/globals.css"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        import('tw-elements');
    }, []);
    return (
        <Layout className="scroll-smooth transition-all">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>

    )
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `important: true` in your `tailwind.config.js` file and it should work.

```
module.exports = {
  important: true, // Add this in config file
  // Rest of the content
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and Raghav Patel comment solved it:

At tailwind.config.js insert *important: true*:

```
module.exports = {
  important: true, // Add this in config file
  // Rest of the content
};
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34421124)